# kendo multiselect values disappear when in editor mode

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, master-detail

I have a master-child setup and in my child grid rows, I have a multi-select that uses a list of strings as datasource. When I click to add/remove entries, the already selected items disappear completely and I can only see the drop down with all the values.

Here is the grid column definition in the child grid:

```
 field: "Teams",
 title: "Team",
 editor: ChildItemEditor,
```

Here is the editor function that creates the multi-select:

```
...
var dataSource = ["Item A" , "Item B"];
...
function ChildItemEditor(container, options)
{
           $('<select multiselect="multiselect" id="ddlItems" name="childItems" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" />')
                        .appendTo(container)
                        .kendoMultiSelect({
                            autoBind: false,
                            dataSource: dataSource,
                            select: function (e) {
                                var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
                                var selectedItem = this.gridMasterData.dataItem(this.gridMasterData.select());

                                if (selectedItem == null) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                options.model.Items = this.value();
                                $(selectedItem.Items).each(function (i, cItem) {
                                    if (options.model.Id == cItem.Id) {
                                        cItem.Items= options.model.Items;
                                        selectedItem.dirty = true
                                    }
                                });
                            },
                        });
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem and what have you got till now. Please elaborate your problem and you will get quick helps. Thank You!

Comment: Hi Nabin, the problem is that the very first time (after a page refresh) the child item box (multiselect) is clicked, only the dropdown containing values show. The existing and already selected items do not appear in the box.
Mind you, when a new selection is made, those items do appear and are saved when save is initiated.

Comment: Found the issue: When reading back data, the second field had a leading space and Multiselect did not automatically Trim the field to bind to it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: When reading back data, the second field had a leading space and Multiselect did not automatically Trim the field to bind to it.